# Implemented early stopping but came across the error SGDClassifier: Not fitted error in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, regularization

Below is the simpler implementation of early stopping which i came across the book and wanted to try it.

```
# Implement SGD Classifier

sgd_clf =   SGDClassifier(random_state=42,
                          warm_start=True,
                          n_iter=1,
                          learning_rate='constant',
                          eta0=0.0005)

minimum_val_error = float('inf')
best_epoch = None
best_model = None

for epoch in range(1000):
  sgd_clf.fit(X_train_scaled,y_train)
  predictions = sgd_clf.predict(X_val_scaled)
  error = mean_squared_error(y_val,predictions)
  if error < minimum_val_error:
    minimum_val_error = error
    best_epoch = epoch
    best_model = clone(sgd_clf)
```

Once the above snippet is executed, best model and best epoch are stored in variable `best_model` and `best_epoch`.So, to test the best_model, i ran the below statement.

```
y_test_predictions = best_model.predict(X_test)
```

But then i came across the error `This SGDClassifier instance is not fitted yet`

Any hints on how to solve this, would be greatly helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `clone` will only copy the estimator with the same parameters, but not with the attached data. So it results a new estimator that has not been fit on the data. Hence, you couldn't use it to make prediction.

Instead of `clone`, you can use either `pickle` or `joblib`.

**1. `pickle`**

```
import pickle
...

for epoch in range(1000):
    ...
    if error < minimum_val_error:
        best_model = pickle.dumps(sgd_clf)
```

Later if you want to use the stored model:

```
sgd_clf2 = pickle.loads(best_model)
y_test_predictions = sgd_clf2.predict(X_test)
```

**2. `joblib`**

You can also use `joblib`, and store the model to the disk.

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
...

joblib.dump(sgd_clf, 'filename.joblib')
```

To use the stored model

```
clf = joblib.load('filename.joblib')
```